# How can I give advantage playing padel and have a fair game?

Tags: etiquette, padel

A friend and me have started to play padel.

The problem is that we have different level and physical condition (without being any of us an expert), and due this the games can be quite boring.

How can I give some advantage and make these matches more interesting for both?

Obviously I'm not talking about playing bad on purpose. For example, when this happens in racing videogames, we have the rule that the more expert player have to use a slower car, but still drive as fast as he can.

Comment: I've don't have enought reputation to create the padel tag, so I've used tennis tag instead

Comment: The more experienced player should learn to play with his/her other hand (I have never heard of this sport, not sure if it's even a one-handed held racquet...).

Comment: @NicholasV. It's very similar to Tennis but with a little boundaries http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padel_(sport)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options that can be used in lawn tennis, which may also work in padel:

- only allow one serve for the stronger player, rather than two
- the weaker player can play to the doubles' lines, but the stronger must play to the singles'
- the weaker player can start each game with a point advantage

Comment: The first and last would work, but not the middle one since there are no doubles' lines in padel. Padel is almost always played as doubles.